# Pattern matching types in Prolog

Tags: prolog, pattern-matching

Let's say I have a list looking like this:

```
List=[alpha(1,2),beta(3,4),gamma(4,1)]
```

Ok, so I want to make a certain pattern matching here... I know I can do:

```
Try=alpha(Y,Z).
    Try=alpha(1,2)
    Y=1
    Z=2
```

But I would like to do for example:

```
Try=X(Y,Z)
    X=alpha
    Y=1
    Z=2
```

...so that I can pass on the data to another predicate:

```
targetPredicate(Type,Value1,Value2):-
    Type=alpha
    ...
```

and then do something with it instead of having to make one help predicate for every type I might run into:

```
helpPredicate(Input):-
    Input=alpha(Value1, Value2),
    targetPredicateAlt(Value1, Value2).

helpPredicate(Input):-
    Input=beta(Value1, Value2),
    targetPredicateAlt(Value1, Value2).

helpPredicate(Input):-
    Input=gamma(Value1, Value2),
    targetPredicateAlt(Value1, Value2).
```

Is there any way to get around this or am I doomed to use a ton of help predicates?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [univ](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2) predicate `=../2`:
Suppose you have `Try=alpha(1,2)`, then

```
Try =..[Name, X, Y].
```

would yield Name = alpha, X = 1, Y = 2.

Comment: Now that was a fast, swift and easy to understand answer.. I almost feel like a fool.. however, that helped me a lot! Thank you!